# update query not work in my code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The update query is not working. This query didn't work.

I tried to print the variable and all variable contain a value

How can i solve this?

**Form code:**

```
echo"<td data-title='Status'>";
if ($percent == 0) {
    echo"<form class='form-inline' role='form' action='";
    ?><?php $_PHP_SELF ?><?php

    echo"' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'> 
    <select id='' name='status' class='form-control input-md'>
    <option valur='.$status.'>$status</option> 
    <option value='Pending'>Pending</option>
    <option value='Cancel'>Cancel</option>
    </select>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<input type='hidden' name='txt_id' value='.$id.'>";
    echo"<td>";
    echo"<input type='submit' name='update' class='btn btn-default' value='Update' />";
} 
else if ($percent >= 1 && $percent < 100) {
    echo"Running";
} 
else if ($percent == 100) {
    echo"Done";
}
echo"</td>";
echo"</form>";
```

**Update code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $ids = $_POST['txt_id'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tbl_project SET db_status='$status' WHERE db_id='$ids'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: specify your error

Comment: it didn't give me an error but it didn't work no update in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) 
First of all try to remove this `value='.$id.'` it should be

```
echo"<input type='hidden' name='txt_id' value='$id'>"
```

beacuse it if your `$id = 1`; then `value = '.$id.'` is equal to `value = '.1.'`;

Same thing for first option value

```
<option valur='.$status.'>$status</option> // this is wrong
```

use this

```
<option value='$status'>$status</option>
```

2) Second try to `echo` your `query` always before running so echo your query

```
 if(isset($_POST['update'])){
       $status=$_POST['status'];
       $ids=$_POST['txt_id'];
     // echo "UPDATE tbl_project SET db_status='$status' WHERE db_id='$ids'";die; just to  debug

        $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE tbl_project SET db_status='$status' WHERE db_id='$ids'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome try updated answer the same thing for status option